# Android Studio how to connect my project with mySQL db (news feed app)

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have searched a lot for the answer but could not find it. Please help me understand how to connect my android app to mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean to have your Android application talk remotely to a server hosting your news feed source (articles, etc.) then you might want to have a look at creating a RESTful service (a basic example of how to achieve this can be found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/)).

You'll want to be familiar with:

- SQL (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)
- JSON (http://www.w3schools.com/json/)
- RESTful services
  (http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069)

Basically what would happen is whenever your activity needs to display news feed results to the user, it can query your RESTful backend (via an http POST/GET request) and wait for your web service to respond. Your web service will listen for HTTP requests matching a specific URL, for example, mynewsfeed.com/get_articles, and upon getting this request, your web service will issue an SQL query against whatever database contains your articles and return the results in an HTTP response.

I'd personally recommend sending data back and for between the server/client using JSON (unless you have a reason for using another format.) This way, when your Android application gets the response from the server, it can parse the JSON data for various attributes contained in your article (title, author, content, etc.)

Google's GSON library has a neat way of converting JSON data into a Java object, so you don't have to worry about manually parsing each JSON field out yourself: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide.

As for how to actually build the web service, there are tons of frameworks out there. I've personally used Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/) in the past and find it very lightweight, straightforward and supported by pretty decent documentation. You'll also need somewhere to host the webservice and store the SQL database (for this I pay ~$30 a year for a simple hosting service and a domain.)

Hope this points you in the right direction (there is a lot of material here.) I'm happy to provide clarification if what I've posted isn't clear.